# Wamp does not show any thing on http://localhost

Tags: localhost, wampserver

I have installed wamp server on windows 7. Its saying **You don't have permission to access the page** when i type **http://localhost/phpmyadmin** but doing well when i type **127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin**.

I am ok with it but just want to know is this some window restriction??

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop IIS Services

If you wish to keep both running - http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-run-wamp-server-parallel-with-iis-7-on-windows/

Comment: is IIS server installe dby default in windows 7? i did not install it?

Comment: You might have installed it while installing components. Please check